# Are there cases of editing HTML output by Aspose.Word with CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, aspose, ckeditor4.x, aspose.words, ckeditor5

I am in trouble with the event that the sentence edited in CKEditor are not output to Word as a result of inheriting attributes of “**-aw-import:ignore**”.

A tag with this attribute is a tag that conveys the attribute of the original word when converting from html to word, and it is not output as word as a meta tag.

If the sentence entered in CKEditor **inherits the attributes**, it will **not** be output as word by mistake.

Comment: Custom “-aw-*” CSS properties are part of round-trip information written by Aspose.Words. But, output of this information can be turned off by setting the HtmlSaveOptions.ExportRoundtripInformation property to 'false'. If you want to save Word document to HTML and then again HTML to Word by using Aspose.Words, you should only then set 'true' value to HtmlSaveOptions.ExportRoundtripInformation. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Sorry for lack of explanation.

When converting from Word to HTML and further from that HTML to Word, I know that ExportRoundtripInformation **must be "true"**.

What I want to know is that "-aw-import: ignore" is output in the default state of true, and it identifies what exists originally and what was inherited by editing by CKEditor and output Then delete the latter. 

specifically, **I would like to know if there is a system that combines CKEditor and Aspose, or if there is a development case.**

Comment: What I understand is that CKEditor is removing "-aw-*" CSS properties from Aspose.Words generated HTML. And when you convert CKEditor's HTML back to Word, you see unexpected No-Break Space characters. "-aw-import:ignore" property tells Aspose.Words that non-breaking space characters did not exist in the original Word document. After CKEditor removes "-aw-import:ignore", nothing can tell Aspose.Words that non-breaking space should not be preserved and it considers these characters meaningful as any other text and preserves them upon importing. So, this is an expected outcome.

Comment: I am afraid, there is no system in development which would make Aspose.Words compatible with CKEditor. Perhaps, you should contact CKEditor's Support and ask them to preserve these special Aspose.Words CSS properties.

Comment: thx.Since Aspose uses the ignore attribute during the paragraph, etc. for adjustment of the height of the line,
 it is not designed in consideration of the editing by the Web editor such as CKEditor,
 so it responds in a way other than non-outputting Do you have plans to do it?

Comment: If I edit HTML the converted from Word with Aspose, I have to consider the logic to remove the attribute of ignore in span tags other than the original that inherited the ignore attribute added by CKEditor editing .

To do that, I must know the specification to output the ignore attribute.
Please present the output specification of Aspose.Words CSS properties. 
I think that it is not a confidential matter. 
It is also necessary information when inquiring CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Words writes this "-aw-import:ignore" only when it needs to make certain elements visible in HTML that would otherwise be collapsed and hidden by web browsers e.g. empty paragraphs, space sequences, etc.

Currently we mark only the following elements with “-aw-import:ignore”:

- Sequences of spaces and non-breaking spaces that are used to simulate
  padding on native list item (`<li>`) elements.
- Non-breaking spaces that are used to prevent empty paragraphs from collapsing.

However, note that this list is not fixed and we may add more cases to it in the future.

Also, please note that Aspose.Words write `&#xa0;` instead of `&nbsp;` because `&nbsp;` is not defined in XML. And by default Aspose.Words generate XHTML documents (*i.e. HTML documents that comply with XML rules*).

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below list of custom styles that Aspose.Words uses to save extra information in output HTML and usually this information is used for Aspose.Words-HTML-Aspose.Words round-trip. We will add description of these entities in documentation as soon as possible.

1. -aw-comment-author
2. -aw-comment-datetime
3. -aw-comment-initial
4. -aw-comment-start
5. -aw-comment-end
6. -aw-footnote-type
7. -aw-footnote-numberstyle
8. -aw-footnote-startnumber
9. -aw-footnote-isauto
10. -aw-headerfooter-type
11. -aw-bookmark-start
12. -aw-bookmark-end
13. -aw-different-first-page
14. -aw-tabstop-align
15. -aw-tabstop-pos
16. -aw-tabstop-leader
17. -aw-field-code
18. -aw-wrap-type
19. -aw-left-pos
20. -aw-top-pos
21. -aw-rel-hpos
22. -aw-rel-vpos
23. -aw-revision-author
24. -aw-revision-datetime

Comment: Thank you for the information, but this is not everything, right?

At a minimum, there are -aw-field-start, -aw-field-separator, and -aw-field-end in addition to -aw-field-code for attributes beginning with aw-field-*: and secondary attributes after colon.

Unfortunately, these attributes disappear without being parsed by CKEDitor and are in trouble.
 Please tell me the information on -aw-field- as soon as possible.

Comment: CKEditor seems to delete tags with only attributes with no element.
Please tell me the type and detail of attribute that conveys information only with the attribute like -aw-field-code:PAGE.

Comment: We have logged your comments in our issue tracking system. We will keep you posted on further updates and also let you know when your issues will be resolved.